# How to solve mutiple reference issue regarding linked server?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I have multiple errors that are linked to references with the linked servers, I have enabled each one of them in the VS project but I cannot seem to solve the errors, We have been using db1..proc_1, can this needs to be resolved something to db1.dbo.proc1, in order to fix the reference issues, and does this needs to be done for all of the databases?

Comment: You mention linked servers (4-part names) but your examples are only database references (3-part names). To reference other databases in your SSDT database project, add a database reference to the other project in your solution along with a SQLCMD variable (e.g. `$(DB1)`). The proc source code can then reference the external database using 3-part names like `[$(DB1)].dbo.proc1`.

Comment: What about the open queries?  whenever I try to generate a dacpac I get a warning and error:

*** Error validating element [dbo].[prc_Rcpt_BO_UUTRCTI]: The column definition
from this OPENQUERY function cannot be verified, and the operations involved wit
h it might not be understood correctly.